# ¿Cómo hacer que el último elemento del map tome el formato correcto?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
    for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){        
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
    }
    return arr;
};

var startDate = new Date();

var daylist = getDaysArray(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 5),new Date());
daylist = (daylist.map((v)=>v.toISOString().slice(0,10)).join(" 00:00:00"));


for (i=0;i<daylist.length;i++)
{
    document.write(daylist[i]); 

}
```

sin embargo en el último elemento no se agrega el formato  `00:00:00`.
¿Cómo es posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puede hacer esto:

```js
var getDaysArray = function(start, end) {
    for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){        
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
    }
    return arr;
};

var startDate = new Date();

var daylist = getDaysArray(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 5),new Date());
daylist = (daylist.map((v)=>v.toISOString().slice(0,10)).join(" 00:00:00 ")) + " 00:00:00";


for (i=0;i<daylist.length;i++)
{
        document.write(daylist[i]); 
  
}
```

el *map* lo que hece es transformar los elements de una colección, lo que pasa es que el *join* une una colección por lo que uested le diga, en este caso "00:00:00" pero piense en tener n trozos de madera y unirlas con pegamento entre ellas, usted an la cara forntal de la primera no pone peganmento, ni en la cara final de la última, eso mismo pasa con el *join*, no pone "00:00:00" después de la última tiene q ponerlos usted

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Por nada me alegro que haya resuelto su problema